# iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml() throwing exception as the document has no pages using WebBrowser in windows application

Tags: c#

Can any one please help me arround as i am using below code:

```
var ex_html = wbBrowser.DocumentText;    
using (var srHtml = new StringReader(ex_html))
                            {
                            //Parse the HTML
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                        }
```

But while getting instance i am facing a runtime exception as '**the document has no pages**'.

Also i have identical itextSharp and XMLWorker but still facing this issue.

Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of paragraph and add paragraph into document.

Comment: I have done this but again i am getting issue of HTML parsing. like Expected > tag: < top_level_menu_trees_array.length/> near line 100, column 57